# Get AD Environment Tab Properties

Tags: powershell

Any direction or know if its remotely possible to query properties for the Environment Tab. Primarily looking to see if a user object has the client devices selected or not.

Using

```
Get-ADUser $samaccountname -Properties *
```

I don't see any property to expand that would give me an indication of these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) right on the bottom

> The **Environment**, Sessions, Remote Control, and Terminal Services Profile pages are supplied for a user object to support terminal services. The UI elements for these pages **do not correspond to individual attributes**. Instead, the settings are stored in private data within Active Directory Domain Services. The terminal services settings can be accessed with the `IADsTsUserEx` interface.

So knowing that we need to use a slighty different approach for getting those details

```
$user = Get-ADUser samaccountname | Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
([adsi]("LDAP://$user")).ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon -eq $true
```

That would return if the `ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon` box is checked. You can refer to another [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380823(v=vs.85).aspx) article for the other attribute names.

```
ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon
ConnectClientPrintersAtLogon
DefaultToMainPrinter
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I poked around on that same page and apparently blew right over that segment to impatient to fully read it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here [Managing Terminal Services attributes with PowerShell](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/02/13/managing-terminal-services-attributes-with-powershell/)

In particular this statement:

"**Important**: Terminal services properties are only available when AD cmdlets are run on Windows Server 2003 or 2008. Workstation operating systems (XP, Vista) do not support programmatic TS administration so the properties will not be retrieved."

I can confirm this extends to Windows 7.

Comment: Looking at Matt's answer I can see that this is a bit out of date... Ah well :)